# Choose the power of 10 to display in R, for formatting error in scientific notation

Tags: r, scientific-notation, significant-digits

I'm writing a program in R in order to estimate the value of a physical constant.

At the end of the program, after I get the result I wanted I'd like to put it in a plot in the format "value +- error".

**In order to make that more readable I want the exponential to be the same in both the value and the error**, but because the error is much smaller than the value, R automatically writes it with the closest power of 10.

Moreover, because it is an absolute error I'd like it to be with 1 significant digit.

**How should I write the text command**?
I am currently writing

```
text(1000, 2.0e-06,paste("Carica specifica =",format(CS11, digits=4),"+-",formatC(ECS1[1], digits=1)))
```

**Which gives on screen:**

```
"1.52e+11+-9e+09"
```

**Instead I'd like to get something like:**

```
"1.5e+11+-0.1+e11"
```

What should I write?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Calculate it yourself:

```
x <- 1.52e11
se <- 9e9
e <- floor(log10(x))

sprintf("Carica specifica = %.1fe+%d +- %.1fe+%d", x/10^e, e, se/10^e, e)
#[1] "Carica specifica = 1.5e+11 +- 0.1e+11"
```

This assumes that x >= 1. If that assumption is not valid, some slight modifications would be necessary.